Can we store always encrypted column into temp table in Azure SQL Database?
I have encrypted a column in Azure SQL Database and now when a proc which has used temp table and being used to UPDATE/INSERT data into always encrypted table. The exception detail is
Msg 33293 Level 16 Cannot find the column encryption key because it does not exists or you do not have permission.

I am not able to find the solution of it.

@Charlieface, For Azure SQL DB, you can not see tempdb. It is valid for Managed Instance.

Local or global temp table?

@J.D. , I am testing on local temp table as of now.

What is the end goal? A local temp table is only accessible to the session that spawned it, so seems a little pointless to use an encrypted column. But I could be mis-thinking about the use case.

@J.D., Ideally we use temp table to hold some intermediate data and do some manipulation on the data and then use for end-goal. And obviously it is being used within session only. This complete step is within a proc where this error is coming.

So why encrypt the temporary table data?

I suggest you add more details to the post. I'm not clear on the steps. Like if you have a "source" table which ha encrypted column, from which you store data into a temp table and then expect to add data into some other table (possibly with encrypted columns). OR some other scenario. I.e., and end-to-end description of the data including what/where is using always encrypted.

@TiborKaraszi , well It is not necessary that I am taking data from Encrypted column on the first place instead I am trying to do data insert into an encrypted column using a temp table. There's no pulling encrypted data and then readding to any encrypted column. I think it is as simple as it is.

@J.D. I didn't say to encrypt temporary table data. It is the temp table when being used with another table on which always encryption applied for a column we get this issue. I hope it is clear enough.

So you have data in a temp table, unencrypted and you want to insert from there to a table that has always encrypted columns? Encryption is done client side (which is the whole purpose of AE). So you would have to grab the data to the client and send it from there to the server, allowing your API to encrypt the data. That is my understanding.
